# The link in the img src is not showing any picture

Tags: html, css, sass

**The below** code is not showing any image why is that at first the link was JPG and the i replaced it using jpg(lowercase) still didn't work. Also is it because the link is http?

```
<img src="http://wp13442953.server-he.de/MT/pics/02_web/001_MT/Variant/Kollektion/Chester/RD-3/RD-3-190x190R---1.jpg" alt="" width="100px" height="100px">
```

```html
    <img src="http://wp13442953.server-he.de/MT/pics/02_web/001_MT/Variant/Kollektion/Chester/RD-3/RD-3-190x190R---1.jpg" alt="" width="100px" height="100px">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it is because you are trying to load an http resource, change it to an image hosted with certificate and it should work

Answer (score 1):

Try to open console in dev tools and you will see the next code error `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` and the url with image will contain secure `httpS` instead of `http` protocol.

If it's possible just send image by secure protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it should work good and nothing wrong with the code snippet you have shared.
The problem would be like the position and size of image

Comment: what do you mean by position of the image? it has nothing to do with the displaying part of the process